# Home folder permission in Ubuntu for apache public_html

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, chmod, umask

I read a lot about that here, but I guess I just can't get it. So here is what I got:
I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed and I just created vhost for a domain, let's call it example.com. I also created a user "example". So I want to host my domain in /home/example/public_html/ and I added it as path in my vhost config. But the problem is that Apache can't execute .PHP files or it can not access that folder (I'm not sure). I guess it is because of the permissions? Note that user "example" is not added to any specific group. I also want to know what umask should I have for that user, just to be sure that every time when the user upload a file using FTP it will be OK for apache.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you don't have PHP installed: `apt-get install php5` should tell you whether you need to install it or not.

Unless Apache is locked right down it's unlikely to be permissions because PHP doesn't really `execute` files.

Comment: It is installed. I guess the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Are you using a specific PHP package for uploading files (like `phpbb`) ? For security (anything where you let users put files on Servers is insecure) I'd recommend carefully reading the package's installation files to be safe. If you're not using a package then try setting your user's upload directory to `chmod 0755 /home/user/upload` to test it and then tighten permissions up afterwards and that might help for testing.

Comment: I actually fixed it. I was uploading files using FTP but the ftp server was configured with umask 077 rather than 022. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad it's working.